# Getting Error in Stack(Push & Pop)

Tags: c, data-structures, stack

i am new to c programming, While implementing stack using c program, It is giving me an error.

In spite of having 5 elements-space in my stack array, it's giving me "Stack Overflow"(message) in my Second iteration of for loop(While Pushing elements).

& While popping out the numbers, only the first number is popped(5 times)

what seems to be wrong?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
# define MAX 5
int stack1[MAX];
int top=-1;
void push(int);
int pop();
void display();
main()
{
int choice,num;
while(1)
{
    printf("\nEnter Your Choice: \n");
    printf("Enter 1. to Push \n");
    printf("Enter 2. to pop \n");
    printf("Enter 3. to Display \n");
    printf("Enter 4. To Exit\n");
    scanf("%d",&choice);
switch(choice)
{

case 1:
    printf("Enter Elements to be pushed\n");
    int z;
    for(z=1;z<=5;z++)
    {
    printf("Enter a the code In Room %d: ",z);
    scanf("%d",&num);
    push(num);//Function call, Calling push
    }
    break;
case 2:
    printf("Numbers to be poped\n");
    int b;
    for(b=1;b<=5;b++)
    {
    num=pop();
    }//Return a integer Value;
    break;

case 3:
    display();
    break;
case 4:
    exit(1);
default:
    printf("Invalid Choice\n");
}
}
} 
void push(int element)//Push Function
{
int x;
for(x=1;x<=5;x++)
{
if(top== MAX-1)//Check if Stack is Full
{
    printf("Stack Overflow \n");
    return;//Terminate the function
}
top=top+1;//start from -1 and gets incremented
stack1[top]=element;//insert elements at each step
}
}
int pop()
{
int a;
for(a=1;a<=5;a++)
{

int element;
if(top==-1)
{
    printf("Stack EMPTY can't delete anything");
     return;
}
element=stack1[top];//In stack Elements are Always delete from TOP
top=top-1;//To shift the pointer
printf("%d has been deleted \n", element);
return element;
}
}
void display()
{
int i;
if(top==-1)
{
    printf("Stack Is empty can't display");
    return;//Terminates Display function
}
printf("\n\n");
for(i=top;i>=0;i--)//Displays top elements and decrements on each step
    printf("%d\n",stack1[i]);
}
```

Comment: That stackoverflow message has nothing to do with your stack data structure :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be using the '**for**' loops for popping,pushing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
# define MAX 5
int stack1[MAX];
int top=-1;
void push(int);
int pop();
void display();
main()
{
int choice,num;
while(1)
{
    printf("\nEnter Your Choice: \n");
    printf("Enter 1. to Push \n");
    printf("Enter 2. to pop \n");
    printf("Enter 3. to Display \n");
    printf("Enter 4. To Exit\n");
    scanf("%d",&choice);
switch(choice)
{

case 1:
    printf("Enter Elements to be pushed\n");
    int z;
    for(z=1;z<=5;z++)
    {
    printf("Enter a the code In Room %d: ",z);
    scanf("%d",&num);
    push(num);//Function call, Calling push
    }
    break;
case 2:
    printf("Numbers to be poped\n");
    int b;
    for(b=1;b<=5;b++)
    {
    num=pop();
    }//Return a integer Value;
    break;

case 3:
    display();
    break;
case 4:
    exit(1);
default:
    printf("Invalid Choice\n");
}
}
} 
void push(int element)//Push Function
{
int x;

if(top== MAX-1)//Check if Stack is Full
{
    printf("Stack Overflow \n");
    return;//Terminate the function
}
top=top+1;//start from -1 and gets incremented
stack1[top]=element;//insert elements at each step

}
int pop()
{
int a;


int element;
if(top==-1)
{
    printf("Stack EMPTY can't delete anything");
     return;
}
element=stack1[top];//In stack Elements are Always delete from TOP
top=top-1;//To shift the pointer
printf("%d has been deleted \n", element);
return element;

}
void display()
{
int i;
if(top==-1)
{
    printf("Stack Is empty can't display");
    return;//Terminates Display function
}
printf("\n\n");
for(i=top;i>=0;i--)//Displays top elements and decrements on each step
    printf("%d\n",stack1[i]);
}
```

Comment: Why? is for not allowed?

Comment: for is popping the first element 5 times, The way I edited your program makes sense. You can push elements one at a time and pop one at a time. Pushing all elements at once and popping doesn't fit good for stacks.

Comment: Yeah, i know, but in order to solve this problem statement, i need to take 5 elements at ONE GO, and pop them out in one go, so, i thought for loop should be the best way to do it. Can you suggest some other way to implement it.

Comment: Thanks, you're the best!

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 for loops. There is a loop in the main function, inside the switch and there is also a loop inside the `push` and `pop` functions.

The `push` and `pop` functions will `push` or `pop` only one element and will not require a loop inside that.

This would be more apparent if you used indenting while writing the code. Which is one of the reasons to properly indent your code.

Comment: Yeah, i know, but in order to solve this problem statement, i need to take(push) 5 elements at ONE GO, and pop them out in one go, so, i thought for loop should be the best way to do it. Can you suggest some other way to implement it

Comment: You already have a loop in the main function which will push 5 elements. If you have another loop in the push function, you are trying to push a total of 25 elements. Actually, since your array size is 5, what happens is that the first element is pushed 5 times, and the rest of the 4 elements try to push (5 times each) but find the stack full. So, when you try to pop, you pop out the first element 5 times.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take this one step at a time.

1).You started a for loop so that the user can enter 5 elements for your stack. Once he enters the number, your push function gets called. In push, again you have a loop which is running 5 times. Thus, the same element is being pushed 5 times to the stack. So on your next  choice the stack is already full. Thus the stack overflow message.

2). Now your stack is something like- [5,5,5,5,5], assuming 5 was the 5 number entered, in your pop function again you are running a loop. Ideally, you are only supposed to pop one element at a time for the user. So since you are running a loop, all 5 elements are getting popped and since only the first element is in the stack, that's what you see in the output.

Comment: So, what changes shud i make in the program to shift the pointer and take(push) different elements at each iteration?

Comment: Okay. Since you already have loop running which is accepting elements from the user, you simple pass that element to your push function. In your push function what you have currently, you will have to remove the for loop because of the reason I explained above. You will simple take that element, increment the top value and do stack[top] = yourNewValue. Simple. Also, just wanted to mention, when u define an array of 5, the index stars from 0. So your loop would be something like, for(i=0;i<=4;i++) and not from 1 to 5 since stack[5] is undefined.